# ODP.Net and create database notification

Tags: oracle, odp.net, odp.net-managed

i am using ODP.net (or rather Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll) to create change notification. It works fine, however I have one problem. It occurs when Windows is starting. Sometimes my application starts before "something oracle proccess" and creating change notification ends with fail. My question what process/service should work to be sure that my application can create change notification on oracle database?

Comment: Are you able to at least connect to the Oracle Database from the code in this case? What is the exact error you get? If the database is simply not up yet and so you fail to connect, maybe you can set up a retry loop on the error.

Comment: Yes i am able to connect to database. I was thinking about loop, but the problem is I dont know how to determine if in oracle change notification (row, event in database) already exists. If exists and I create one more it will be double notification and i want to avoid this,

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: My question for now is - How to check if notification for xxx application already exists?

Comment: You can see what is registered by running the query given in this documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_cqn.htm#ADFNS1301

Comment: (eg you select against the USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS table)

Comment: Yes i can use this tables. I read that if I set Timeout to 0 it will be infinity notification. And this is what I want. The problem is that often when I restart server, row (notification) in this table with Timeout 0 is deleted. So what 0 in timeout mean? I would like to create one notification for eternity. After restart of my application I want get callback without create new notification.